# Is there a way to know for sure whether a project does not exist in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Good afternoon all,

I work at an organization where a few different teams can interact with a given Google Cloud project. Each team keeps references to the Google Cloud project, but if/when a Google project is deleted, each team is not always notified of this action. This results in teams having references to old, non-existent projects.

I have tried to use [gsutil projects describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/describe) to test for a project's existence, but according to the documentation:

> This command can fail for the following reasons:
>
> - The project specified does not exist.
> - The active account does not have permission to access the given project.

This ends up looking something like this:

```
> gcloud projects describe Project_Name

ERROR: (gcloud.projects.describe) User [My_Admin_Uuer] does not have permission to access projects instance [Project_Name] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

Is there a way to know for sure whether this project exists and if so, which permissions I need to view the project description?